# Animate div from middle

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this code. I want the div to animate from middle and cover whole space .like this
[image]

HTML

```
 <div id="wrap">    
    <div class="anim"></div>    
  </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.anim').on('mouseover',function(){

  $(this).animate({
    height:200,
    width:300,
    right:100        
  });     

});


$('.anim').on('mouseover',function(){

  $(this).animate({
    height:100,
    width:100        
  });

});
```

Tried many times but it is only animating left or right.

Demo http://jsbin.com/uqEcajEm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `margin-left: 100px` on your `.anim` to `margin: 0 auto` this should work, see http://jsbin.com/uqEcajEm/2

It keeps the box always centered.

Comment: What do you want to happen with each div when there's two of them?

Comment: Actually i want the divs that are in middle to expand from between. Im able to expand the divs on extreme left and right to left & right but was unable to expand the middle one

Comment: Is this what you want? I think you have to handle the left and the middle one separately. http://jsbin.com/uqEcajEm/6/

Comment: Superb yup thats what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
<style id="jsbin-css">
#wrap{border:1px solid #000;height:200px;width:300px;position:relative}

.anim{border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:100px;margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;}
</style>
<script src="JS%20Bin_files/ga.js" async="" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="JS%20Bin_files/edit.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
  <div id="wrap">

    <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; right: 100px;" class="anim"></div>

  </div>
<script>
$('.anim').on('mouseover',function(){

  $(this).animate({
    height:200,
    width:300,

  });


});


$('.anim').on('mouseover',function(){

  $(this).animate({
    height:100,
    width:100,

  });


});
</script>
```